# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'add'

Tags: django

I have seen lots of posts for this error, but none having to do with "add". I get this when I click "Add Section Attribute" in the admin interface.

By commenting out:

```
notAllowedCoursePair = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)
```

from my SectionAttributes model I have determined this line is causing the issue. Removing blank=True does not help. When I remove the whole line, add works fine. However, it looks pretty harmless to me. The same as some other ManyToManyFields I have. Is there something special about the "Course" table it links to?

```
class Course(models.Model):
    bb_course_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade_level = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SectionAttributes(models.Model):
    num_required_courses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_drop_downs = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    grade = models.ManyToManyField(Grade)
    section = models.ManyToManyField(Section)
    term = models.ManyToManyField(Term)
    instructions = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    checkboxes = models.ManyToManyField(Checkbox, blank=True)
    notAllowedCoursePair = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)
    on_change_popup = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    student_num_requested = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.section.all()) + " " + str(self.term.all()) + " " + str(self.grade.all())
```

Comment: Could you also post the source for CGPS_Registration/registration/admin.py?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction! It was in fact an problem in my SectionAttributesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) which I now know how to fix. I was calling full_path.split('/')[4] to get the id from the path, which obviously isn't there when its an "add", only when it is a view of an existing record.